# executeBatch Exception Handling

Tags: java, sql, jdbc

executeBatch() will throw two exceptions SQLException and BatchUpdateException. Need help on how tohandle this exception.

We are executing a 900 batch limit and 150 commit limit for a distributed environment. Handled only the only BatchUpdateException. Below is the code snippet. Can some one guide whether we need to catch SQLException. If the  SQLException is not caught what is the result.

Throws:
    SQLException - if a database access error occurs, this method is called on a closed Statement or the driver does not support batch statements. --- What does this statement means.

```
} catch (BatchUpdateException be) {

    status = "failure";
    errorDesc = "BatchUpdateException";
    errorCode = "-1";
    checkpoint = "12";
    log.debug(DealerId + "->BatchException be:" + be + ", checkpoint: " + checkpoint
            + ",con: " + con + ",db2con: " + db2Con);

    int[] updateStatus = be.getUpdateCounts();

    if (updateStatus != null) {
        ArrayList<String> failedList = new ArrayList<String>();
        try {
            verifyUpdateCount(updateStatus, failedList, batchQueryList, queryList);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            if (failedList.size() > 0) {
                log.debug(DealerId + "->updateStatus Exception queryList size:"
                        + queryList.size());
                queryList.clear();
                queryList.addAll(failedList);
            }
            log.debug(DealerId + "->updateStatus Exception e:" + e + ", checkpoint: "
                    + checkpoint + "con: " + con + "db2con: " + db2Con);
        }
    }
    break END;
} finally {
    try {
        log.debug("norecords:" + noRecords);
        if (!noRecords) {
            closeStatements(ps, rs, rsShdw, db2Ps, stShdw);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        printCheckpoint(queryList, con, db2Con, "closeStatements Exception e: ", e,
                checkpoint);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Throws: SQLException - if a database access error occurs, this method is called on a closed Statement or the driver does not support batch statements. --- What does this statement means.

I don't know if it can get much simpler than that. Which part do you not understand?

It says that the method throws `SQLException` in one of the following circumstances:

- database access error occurs,
- this method is called on a closed Statement
- the driver does not support batch statements.

Comment: BatchUpdateException is caught should we catch the SQLException also. Is this required?.

Comment: `BatchUpdateException extends SQLException` so if you catch the latter you don't need to catch the former, unless you want to treat it differently